# Solve Aristotle's Number Problem

Tags: code-golf, game, hexagonal-grid

Aristotle's number puzzle is the challenge of populating each of 19 cells in a hexagonal grid with a unique integer between 1 and 19 such that the total along every axis is 38.

You can picture the game board looking like this:

[image: aristotle grid]

And the puzzle, in essence, is the solution to the following set of fifteen equations:

```
((a + b + c) == 38 && (d + e + f + g) == 38 && (h + i + j + k + l) == 
   38 && (m + n + o + p) == 38 && (q + r + s) == 38 && (a + d + h) == 
   38 && (b + e + i + m) == 38 && (c + f + j + n + q) == 
   38 && (g + k + o + r) == 38 && (l + p + s) == 38 && (c + g + l) == 
   38 && (b + f + k + p) == 38 && (a + e + j + o + s) == 
   38 && (d + i + n + r) == 38 && (h + m + q) == 38)
```

Where each variable is a unique number in the set `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19}`.

There are multiple possible solutions, and are `19!` possible combinations of integers, so naive brute force will be impractical.

Rules:

1. No hardcoding the answer or looking up the answer elsewhere; your code needs to find it on its own
2. Speed doesn't matter, but you do have to show your results, so code that takes 1000 years to run won't help you
3. Find all the answers
4. Treat answers that are identical under rotation as identical
5. Deduct 5% of your total byte count if you output the results in an attractive honeycomb
6. Fewest bytes wins

Comment: Great question, looking forward to working a solution to it.

Comment: Do you consider rotated answers as unique? E.g. let's assume a, b, c = 1, 18, 19 indexes a particular solution, if we set c, g, l = 1, 18, 19 and all other values are "rotated" to match, do you consider this a unique solution?

Comment: @ProgrammerDan Rotated answers are identical. I will clarify.

Comment: A hexagon has more symmetries than just rotations. What about answers which are identical under a combination of rotaation and reflection?

Comment: Interested to see a solution to this one using self-organising maps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code Solution for the Magic Hexagon](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6304/code-solution-for-the-magic-hexagon)

Comment: @PeterTaylor Might be self-serving, as this question does appear to be a close duplicate, but I believe this is much better described and has a better "win" condition, and other features that highlight it as a better question, and as such should remain open.

Comment: Wondering why an answer with a higher byte count was accepted for code-golf?

Comment: @bazzargh That answer must not have been there when I gave the checkmark, or it was subsequently improved. Or I missed it. Anyway, fixed it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Haskell <s>295</s> 289

```
import Data.List
t=38
y a b=[max(19-b)(a+1)..19]
w=y 0 t
x=filter((==w).sort)$[[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,t-a-e-o-s,k,l,m,t-d-i-r,o,p,q,r,s]|a<-[1..14],c<-y a a,l<-y a c,s<-y a l,q<-y a s,h<-y c q,e<-w,let{f=t-g-e-d;i=t-b-e-m;o=t-r-k-g;k=t-p-f-b;b=t-a-c;g=t-l-c;p=t-l-s;r=t-q-s;m=t-q-h;d=t-a-h}]
```

Another similar answer, using arithmetic to get the intermediate hexes. Unlike the other solutions, I don't test for those sums being > 0, testing that the sorted hexes are equal to the range [1..19] is enough. a, c and h are restricted so that only uniquely rotated/mirrored solutions are allowed. The solution appears after a few seconds, then there's a wait of a minute or so while it decides there's no more.

Usage in ghci:

```
ghci> x
[[3,19,16,17,7,2,12,18,1,5,4,10,11,6,8,13,9,14,15]]
```

Edited to shave a few chars. 'y 0 t' produces [1..19].

Comment: Actually I'm doing the same thing in my C answer :) damn how could I not see that Haskell is the perfect tool for the job :P +1

Comment: I get to miss out your `x>0` check, because I sort the list including negatives instead of incrementing an array? On the other hand, I have to restrict the ranges (my `y a b`) to get Haskell to perform, which costs me a few chars. But there's bound to be another language that has built-in sort that'll beat me working the same way (looking at you, Mathematica).

Comment: Yes, sorting in C unfortunately is not as simple as in Haskell. The problem with Mathematica is that it's not compiled and thus so damn slow :(

Comment: I always do these in Haskell for practice, even if another language would be better.

Comment: I actually program Haskell as a side job, so I'm stumped at that it didn't even occur to me to use it here :D It's a really great language, even in the real/impure world

Answer (score 10):

## Java <strike>(1517 - 75.85) = 1441.15</strike> <strike>(1429 - 71.45) = 1357.55</strike> (1325 - 66.25) = 1258.75

This was fun.

Prints all unique solutions w.r.t. mirroring and rotation, in a pleasant honeycomb (hence 5% reduction)

Runtime: ~0.122s (122 milliseconds) on my 4 year old laptop.

Golfed code (*edit* realized I was stupidly repeating my printfs, reduced them to a single printf for maximum golf) (*new edit* Reduced calls to Set functions into clever smaller functions, some other micro-optimizations):

```
import java.util.*;class A{boolean c(Set<Integer>u,int z){return!u.contains(z);}Set<Integer>b(Set<Integer>c,int...v){Set<Integer>q=new HashSet<Integer>(c);for(int x:v)q.add(x);return q;}void w(){Set<Integer>U,t,u,v,w,y,z;int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,X,Z;X=20;Z=38;for(a=1;a<X;a++)for(b=1;b<X;b++)if(b!=a)for(c=1;c<X;c++)if(c!=a&&c!=b&&a+b+c==Z){U=b(new HashSet<Integer>(),a,b,c);for(d=1;d<X;d++)if(c(U,d))for(h=1;h<X;h++)if(h!=d&&c(U,h)&&a+d+h==Z){t=b(U,a,b,c,d,h);for(m=1;m<X;m++)if(c(t,m))for(q=1;q<X;q++)if(q!=m&&c(t,q)&&h+m+q==Z){u=b(t,m,q);for(r=1;r<X;r++)if(c(u,r))for(s=1;s<X;s++)if(s!=r&&c(u,s)&&q+r+s==Z){v=b(u,r,s);for(p=1;p<X;p++)if(c(v,p))for(l=1;l<X;l++)if(l!=p&&c(v,l)&&s+p+l==Z){w=b(v,p,l);for(g=1;g<X;g++)if(c(w,g)&&l+g+c==Z)for(e=1;e<X;e++)if(e!=g&&c(w,e))for(f=1;f<X;f++)if(f!=e&&f!=g&&c(w,f)&&d+e+f+g==Z){y=b(w,g,e,f);for(i=1;i<X;i++)if(c(y,i))for(n=1;n<X;n++)if(n!=i&&c(y,n)&&d+i+n+r==Z&&b+e+i+m==Z){z=b(y,i,n);for(o=1;o<X;o++)if(c(z,o))for(k=1;k<X;k++)if(k!=o&&c(z,k)&&m+n+o+p==Z&&r+o+k+g==Z&&b+f+k+p==Z)for(j=1;j<X;j++)if(c(z,j)&&j!=o&&j!=k&&a+e+j+o+s==Z&&c+f+j+n+q==Z&&h+i+j+k+l==Z){System.out.printf("%6d%4d%4d\n\n%4d%4d%4d%4d\n\n%2d%4d%4d%4d%4d\n\n%4d%4d%4d%4d\n\n%6d%4d%4d\n\n",a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s);return;}}}}}}}}}public static void main(String[]a){(new A()).w();}}
```

> Brute force is passe, but clever use of the fact that only a very small set of solutions exists led me to an iteration based answer, where within each loop of the iteration I only consider integers that have not been "assigned" yet. I make use of Java's HashSet to gain O(1) lookups for numbers that have been used previously. Finally, there are exactly 12 solutions, but when you discount both rotation and mirroring this reduces to just one unique solution, so when the first solution is encountered, I print it out and terminate. Check out my [less-golfed code at github](https://github.com/ProgrammerDan/aristotle-number/blob/master/AristotleNumber.java) for a bit of a clearer view into how I am approaching this solution.

Enjoy!

Comment: Well, you lie in your spoiler, there are more different solutions, so your answer is invalid.

Comment: Strong claim, can you back it up with an answer of your own to prove it? I'm certainly not aware of any intentional lies in my spoiler.

Comment: _so when the first solution is encountered, I print it out and terminate_ rule no. 3 tells tells to find all answers. There 19 as OP said, not sure if it is really 19, but I have run into similar task before, so know that there is more then one.

Comment: You need to read my _entire_ spoiler. I found 12 solutions. Then you need to read the _entire_ comments attached to the question. The OP says that answers that are equal w.r.t rotation are equivalent, and should be skipped. Another person asked if answers equal w.r.t mirroring should be skipped. Although the OP has to date not replied to this query, both my and all the other solutions to date assume the answer is "yes". Hence, my solution is fully complete, fully accurate, and there are no "lies" here. However, if you would like to see all 12 solutions, remove the `return;` statement.

Comment: Finally, this is code golf. Considering adding an arbitrary `return;` statement increases my code length by 7, it would be insane for me to add it if the true answer included all 12 solutions that are simply rotated/mirrored versions of each other. Although insanity cannot be ruled out, in this case, the addition of `return;` was intentional, and as I described, based on the the _full question and comments dialog_, which you should take care to review before tossing accusations. Thanks!

Comment: @ST3 That's just wrong, there are exactly 12 solutions and only one unique solution modulo reflection and rotation.

Answer (score 8):

### C, 366 bytes (<strike>C++ 541 450</strike>)

```
#define R(i)for(int i=19;i;--i)
#define X(x)if(x>0&&!V[x]++)
#define K(X)X(a)X(b)X(c)X(d)X(e)X(f)X(g)X(h)X(i)X(j)X(k)X(l)X(m)X(n)X(o)X(p)X(q)X(r)X(s)
Q(x){printf("%d ",x);}
T=38,V[99];main(){R(h)R(c)R(s)R(a)R(l)R(q)R(e){int d=T-a-h,b=T-a-c,g=T-c-l,p=T-l-s,r=T-q-s,m=T-h-q,f=T-g-e-d,i=T-b-e-m,n=T-d-i-r,o=T-p-n-m,k=T-g-o-r,j=T-h-i-k-l;R(C)V[C]=0;K(X)K(+Q),exit(0);}}
```

Compile with `gcc -std=c99 -O3`.

Prints all unique solutions modulo rotation and mirroring, in the format `a b c d ...`, one per line.

Runtime: 0.8 seconds on my computer.

> We enumerate the cells in the order h -> c -> s -> a -> l -> q -> e for maximum prunability. In fact the version above just tries every 20^7 assignments for those variables. Then we can compute all the other cells. There is only one unique solution modulo rotation/mirroring. An older, less golfed and ~20 times faster (due to pruning) C++ version can be found [on Github](https://gist.github.com/niklasb/9777793)

Comment: I love the largely arithmetic approach here. Bravo! +1

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab: <s>333</s> 320 characters

This is a pretty dumb near-brute-force approach that doesn't use recursion. It builds up partial solutions in `z`, which is printed out at the end. Each column is a solution; elements are listed a-z from top to bottom. Runtime is 1-2 hours.

```
z=[];
a='abc adh hmq qrs spl lgc defg beim mnop dinr rokg pkfb hijkl aejos cfjnq';while a[k,a]=strtok(a);n=length(k);x=nchoosek(1:19,n)';s=[];for t=x(:,sum(x)==38)s=[s,perms(t)'];end
m=0.*s;m(19,:)=0;m(k(1:n)-96,:)=s(1:n,:);y=[];for p=m for w=z m=[];l=w.*p~=0;if p(l)==w(l) y(:,end+1)=w+p.*(~l);end
end
end
z=[m,y];end
z
```

Running from within Matlab:

```
>> aristotle;
>> z(:,1)

ans =

    9
   11
   18
   14
    6
    1
   17
   15
    8
    5
    7
    3
   13
    4
    2
   19
   10
   12
   16
```